# customRenderedBannerViewDelegate implementation

Tags: ios, delegates, google-ad-manager

I tried to implement the **customRenderedBannerViewDelegate** 
as describe in documentation : [DFPBannerView](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/api/reference/Classes/DFPBannerView)

Banner view creation and load

```
    self.dfpBannerView = [[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:self.containerView.bounds];
    self.dfpBannerView.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    self.dfpBannerView.adUnitID = self.adUnitID;
    self.dfpBannerView.validAdSizes = self.validAdSizes;
    self.dfpBannerView.customRenderedBannerViewDelegate = self;
    [self.dfpBannerView loadRequest:request];
```

Then implement the delegate:

```
- (void)bannerView:(nonnull DFPBannerView *)bannerView
didReceiveCustomRenderedAd:(nonnull DFPCustomRenderedAd *)customRenderedAd {

}
```

Any idea of why the delegate is never called ? should I set some specific parameters in my request ? To active customRenderedBanner ?

For information simple delegate is working correctly and the ad is displayed

```
 self.dfpBannerView.delegate = self; // Working perfectly
```

Sample project with DFP banner : 
[stackoverflow-DFPBanner-sample](https://github.com/hiko-prod/stackoverflow-DFPBanner)

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the protocol.

```
@interface ViewController() < DFPCustomRenderedBannerViewDelegate > {
    //....
}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with that library, but since `adViewDidReceiveAd` is being called, it doesn't seem like a custom ad is being loaded and therefore never calling that delegate.  Would test ads trigger a custom  ad delegate?

Comment: I agree but can't find the correct way to trigger the custom delegate, perhaps a parameter in the request, but I didn't found the correcte information in the google documentation ... :s